# c++14 auto lambda does not name a type in jgrasp

Tags: lambda, cygwin, c++14, jgrasp

g++ version: 4.9.2

jgrasp version: 2.0.1_04

Settings used in jgrasp: default

code used to test:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){
    auto glambda = [](auto x){ return x;};
    std::cout << glambda("Hello generic lambda!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

result:

- compiles perfectly when using the cygwin terminal
- jgrasp throws this error when compiling:

  ```
  jGRASP exec: g++ -g -o Test.exe Test.cpp
  |Test.cpp: In function 'int main()':
  |Test.cpp:3:9: error: 'glambda' does not name a type
  |    auto glambda = [](auto x){ return x;};
  |         ^
  |Test.cpp:4:50: error: 'glambda' was not declared in this scope
  |    std::cout << glambda("Hello generic lambda!\n");
  |                                                  ^
  ```

Nothing seems to be out of place. What am i missing here?

Comment: Is it possible that you're missing the "-std=c++14" flag?

Comment: @December If that is the case, how do I add it in Jgrasp? I tried using a custom environment for the commands in 'settings'. It does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for wasting your time. It turns out that I needed to add the "-std=c++14" flag in the 'C/L' section of the compiler environment's settings. I'll be closing this question.